# Why we use $p_x$ and $p_y$ orbitals?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, atomic-physics, physical-chemistry, orbitals

The wavefunction of $2p$ orbitals with $m_l=\pm1$ have the form:
$$\Psi_{p_{\pm1}}=\pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}r\sin\theta\cdot e^{\pm i\phi}f(r)$$
We can make linear combinations and get the $p_x$ and $p_y$ orbitals:
$$\Psi_{p_x}=- \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(p_{_{+1}}-p_{_{-1}})=r\sin\theta \cos\phi \cdot f(r)=xf(r)$$
$$\Psi_{p_y}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(p_{_{+1}}+p_{_{-1}})=r\sin\theta \cos\phi \cdot f(r)=yf(r)$$ 
I understand that because the Hamiltonian operator is linear then every linear combination of wavefunctions is also a solution. What I don't understand is why we use $p_x$ and $p_y$ orbitals (e.g. chemistry) in order to visualize probability densities. They are real-valued functions but they clearly have different probability densities than $p_{_{+1}}$ and $p_{_{-1}}$.

Comment: In short: many of the chemists that don’t struggle so much with complex numbers end up doing a physics degree.

Answer (score 1):

The $p_x$ and $p_y$ orbitals are standing waves. They are not degenerate in energy when spherical symmetry is broken, as in molecules. Then the angular momentum is not constant, and $m_\ell$ is not a good quantum number.

It is the same with the $3d$ orbitals in crystals.

Comment: Are you assuming that the symmetry breaking perturbation is diagonal in the $p_x,p_y$ basis? Otherwise I see no reason to use these. So for perturbation applied along an axis (eg a uniform electric field) this would be a sensible choice I think?

Comment: @jacob1729 As a first approximation, the $p_x$ and $p_y$ orbitals will also be good starting points and intuitive when the perturbation is not diagonal in that basis, when $p_x$ and $p_y$ are not exact eigenstates. But for numerical calculations maybe there is no advantage.